# How to prevent the delay in evaluating ngIf condition in angular 6? Default image is displayed before evaluating the value. How to prevent this?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ng-if

**component.ts**

```
  this.canShowPrivateInfo;

  if (this.canEditDetails || this.loginId == this.loggedInUser) {                    
      this.canShowPrivateInfo = true;
  } else if (this.loggedInUserPrivacy) {
      this.canShowPrivateInfo = false;
  } else {
      this.canShowPrivateInfo =true;
   }
```

This is the condition (  **this.canShowPrivateInfo** ) which is used to toggle between showing protected image and normal image

**HTML**

**PUBLIC IMAGE**

```
<img *ngIf="canShowPrivateInfo" 
     [src]="uploadedImageURL" 
      class="profile-pic"
 >
```

**PROTECTED IMAGE**

```
<span *ngIf="!canShowPrivateInfo" class="profile-pic">
  <i class="fas fa-user-lock profile-lock"></i>
</span>
```

So here even if `canShowPrivateInfo` is true, it is first showing lock image and then it is showing actual image.

It is taking a second to evaluate and then changing.

How can I prevent this flickering of images initially in screen? Which is the best way to toggle between images without flickering?

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz demo of the same?

Comment: Sure. Let me create..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid this flickering you can do:

- Do not assign **false** to **canShowPrivateInfo** as the time of
  declaring the variable.
- Then in HTML add undefined check as well.

eg:

**TS:**

```
public canShowPrivateInfo;
```

**HTML:**

```
<span *ngIf="!canShowPrivateInfo && canShowPrivateInfo !== undefined"
      class="profile-pic">
       <i class="fas fa-user-lock profile-lock"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

can we check 'canShowPrivateInfo' to false like this.

```
 <span *ngIf="canShowPrivateInfo === false" class="profile-pic">
     <i class="fas fa-user-lock profile-lock"></i>
 </span>
```